# Получить число при помощи AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт, который должен получить число.
Есть страничка на которой всего одна строка вида {"temperatura":10}.
Как через AJAX запрос получить это число (в данном примере 10).

Получилась конструкция следующего вида, но почему-то не работает, в чем ошибка.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'произвольный юрл'
    , type: "get"
    , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function (res) {
     var test = res.temperatura;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

```
jQuery.ajax({ url: 'произвольный юрл' , method: "get" , dataType: "json", success: function (data) { var t = data.temperatura; }})
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Так тоже не работает.

Comment: @ТукмачевПавел домой прийду и проверю

Comment: извиняюсь, все правильно, в конце ссылки просто не дописал слеш